# beendet vs zu Ende vs vorbei

Tags: synonym

Is there a difference **in meaning** between these when expressing that something is over / has ended? Examples:

- Der Winter ist beendet / zu Ende / vorbei.
- Die Sitzung ist beendet / zu Ende / vorbei.
- Der Unterricht ist beendet / zu Ende / vorbei.
- Der Krieg ist beendet / zu Ende / vorbei.

Answer (score 3):

Using *beendet* alludes to an actor who made the thing stop. Thus, it works with *Sitzung* and *Unterricht*, and in some cases with *Krieg*, but it doesn't work with *Winter*.

The difference between *zu Ende* and *vorbei* is that *zu Ende* is used only for things that ended recently, whereas *vorbei* remains valid thereafter.